# Message ID and Real IP of the email sender

Tags: anonymity

How I get Real IP of an  email sender using  Message ID   of the said mail?

Comment: There is no sure way to do that. Some email routines use the name or IP of the source computer when generating the message id, some don't. And those which do, don't necessarily do that in Ryde same manner. That being said, are you talking about specific message ids?

Answer (score 0):

The `Message-ID` header can be chosen arbitrarily by the client, so you cannot reliably expect to find the client IP address (if any) encoded in it.

[This page](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/List_of_MUA_Header_Formats) lists known behaviour of many email sending softwares; some (e.g. [mutt](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Mutt_Header_Format)) will encode the full name of the sending machine in the Message-ID, but this is the name as the machine knows it, so it can be "localhost", which is not very informative. Moreover, even if the sending software encoded its known IP address in the header, it would often be a local-only address such as `192.168.1.100` because of the high prevalence of [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). Finally, many emails nowadays are sent through big Webmail platforms like Gmail, so if you find an IP address in it, it will be the address of a Gmail server, *not* the address of the client.